# Remove Black Header from Google Maps Embed Iframe

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-embed

Please take a look at this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lscxuyhe/

Code looks like following:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=zUN79N8r2n1E.kLstghIFzhKU" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

I created custom google maps. Now can't remove black header (Untitled map written)from top of maps iframe. Googled a lot. Nothing found.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

You can hide all buttons with css. Create a containder div width overflow on hidden and the sizes you need. Place the new google maps iframe/embed inside with a largersize. To position the maps iframe use negative marges..

Example with 100% width:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;">
  <iframe 
     src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d39797.07748547086!2d5.46683904751879!3d51.433965676849986!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c6d90575ca5e3d%3A0x55989f5f344b006!2sPrins+Hendrikstraat+5!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1392716144537"
     width="100%"
     height="600"
     frameborder="0"
     style="border:0; margin-top: -150px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Make the iframe 300px higher than your container div. 150px to hide below and 150px to hide on top. To hide this 150 on the top of the iframe use:

margin-top: -150px;

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a major container

```html
<div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "50vh", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <iframe
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d123165.52603602942!2d-93.6386613034247!3d41.937461733360486!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x87ee7756ecd1eed3%3A0x85fac44fbb070b9f!2sMcDonald&#39;s!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1647271469039!5m2!1ses!2sar"
        style={{
          border: "0px",
          width: "100vw",
          height: "500px",
          padding: "0",
          frameborder: "0",
          marginTop: "-50px",
        }}
      ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), you would use `frameborder="0" style="border:0"` but that doesn't seem to work with your map. A gimmicky alternative is to extend the height of your map a bit and cover up the border with some CSS.

Answer (score -2):

It's enough to add negative margin-top: - px; to your iframe as inline CSS

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=xxxxxxxx" 
width="100%" 
height="500"  
style="margin-top: -46px;">
</iframe>
```

This will move the whole map up by -46px inside the iframe, which is height of that ugly gmaps top border in my case...

You can also use class for that iframe and additional CSS in your CSS file

Working example

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1y4xAXW83GJO9OfXK1oDwAfqYDZQKIVBH" width="100%" height="500"  frameborder="0" style="border:0; margin-top: -55px;"></iframe>
```